# Python Calculator having issues

Tags: python, tkinter

So I've added a feature to write percentages efficiently, all you would have to do is have a number, say 6, then press percentage, and the calculator would automatically write out 0.06. It's all working well when you start to type out the expression for the calculator:

[image]

But when you press the equal sign, thats when things go bad:

[image]

Now because I'm horrible at math, I literally thought this was the correct answer, so now i can finally move on to other things, right? But when I googled it, it said that 6*0.06 is 0.36, not 36.

Here's where things get a little bonkers again, when I do 6/0.06, I get 1, not 100, so that means whenever I divide, I get something 100 times lower than the actual answer, whenever I multiply, I get something 100 times higher than what I asked for.

Here is the percent function:

```py
def percent():
  global expression
  last_num = expression[-1]
  percent = int(last_num)/100
  equation.set(f"{expression[:-1]}{percent}")
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is not enough information, like what will be performed when `=` key is pressed.  Better provide a [mre].

Comment: The logic of `percent()` cannot cater situation like `60%`.

Comment: Why don't you update `expression` instead of `equation` inside `percent()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing operations on only the last digit is not going to work for a number having more than 1 digit. Here are modifications I did in the `percent` function, to make the logic work. Also, using the `eval` function to evaluate the expression, gives the desired result for inputs like "6*6", "6/6", and "5/70".

```
from tkinter import *
import string
window = Tk()

entry1string = StringVar()
entry_1 = Entry(window,textvariable=entry1string)
entry_1.pack()

def percent():
    global expression
    expression = entry1string.get()
    #instead of last_num look for entire number e.g. in "60%", "60"
    #so first find the operator which is used in the expression ( /, *, ...etc.)
    operator = next((ele for ele in expression if ele in string.punctuation), None)
    #Now get the number from the last whose % we need to calculate first
    percent_num = expression.split(operator)[-1]   #from the last everything after that '/' or '*' operator
    #Also get the entire rest of the expression
    #i.e. get the number before that operator along with the operator
    rest_exp = expression.split(operator)[0]+operator
    
    #print(percent_num)
    percent = int(percent_num)/100
    exprsn = f"{rest_exp}{percent}"
    print(exprsn)
    ans = eval(exprsn)
    Label(window, text=ans).pack()

button1 = Button(window, text="%", command=percent)
button1.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you notice that `entry_1 = Entry(...).pack()` will assign `None` to `entry_1`? Same on `button1 = Button(...).pack()`.  Although those variables are not used elsewhere, it is not recommended.  Also your answer does not address OP issue.

Comment: Yes, this was just to give an idea. Let me update it.